# How to make a separate Eclipse project out of a subfolder under Git source-control

Tags: eclipse, git, git-submodules, subdirectory, git-subtree

I have a website project with the main files in a root folder and an admin tool in a subfolder. The admin tool includes a few classes from the root folder.

I would like to keep separate version control over the 'site' (root) and the 'admin tool' (subfolder) with Git. With Git ignoring the subfolder in the root and a separate repository in the subfolder this works fine.

However, I like using Eclipse (4.4.2) as my Git GUI but Eclipse manages this on a project basis and when I try to create a new project in Eclipse of the subfolder it complains that this is not allowed because that folder is already part of another project (root folder).

Is there a way, just like in Git, to make Eclipse ignore a subfolder in a project so that I can create a separate project of the subfolder? Or should I approach the whole thing differently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eclipse unfortunately doesn't visually indicate separate changes when using submodules and managing the root folder and the subfolder as separate projects in Eclipse helps me to keeps things separately organized. **That is why I chose to .gitignore the subfolder in the rootfolder and create a separate repo in the subfolder.**

Bringing this to Eclipse was a hassle because there are some [known bugs](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=300964) in Eclipse that (ironically) make EGit ignore the .gitignore file. This makes Eclipse insist on committing the .git folder it finds in the subfolder as a submodule, even though it should be ignoring it.

I now have everything setup using the following steps:

1. creating a **symbolic link** (Windows) of the subfolder to a folder next to the root folder. This helps bypass the Eclipse restriction of creating projects in subfolders of folders that are themselves already a project.
2. **creating the repos before adding the projects** to Eclipse, otherwise
   Eclipse will not use the .gitignore file. Even if you use EGit to
   create them.
3. Writing the .gitignore file with **Unix style line breaks**, using a **forward slash** to ignore the /subfolder. Git itself handles other formats fine but Eclipse won't use the .gitignore correctly if it isn't exactly written that way.
4. To clean things up; hiding the subfolder from the 'site' (root) project by adding a **Recourse Filter** on the project that hides the subfolder from the project tree. This way, the file from the 'admin tool' subfolder can only be accessed in Eclipse through its own project.

I now have two separate projects in Eclipse with each their own Git repository, even though one is technically a subfolder of the other. 
I wrote a details tutorial about this in this post about [managing a subfolder as a project in Eclipse, Git and FTP](http://thedevnotes.allcoolandnew.com/managing-subfolder-as-project-eclipse-git-ftp/).

Answer (score 2):

#### The right and convenient way:

You can make a submodule out of that folder with git-subtree command.

After making a submodule you will be able to manage your project as two git repos, one nested in another. **Eclipse must understand this structure** and allow to make separate commits. You also will be able to have different remote repositories for each of your sub-projects.

Here's a good manual on git-subtree:
[Detach (move) subdirectory into separate Git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359424/detach-subdirectory-into-separate-git-repository)

#### The not so right and convenient way.

You can add that subfolder in .gitignore of the main folder and then initiate a new repo inside it.

Comment: Yes. That takes care of the Git part (2nd paragraph). My problem is more with how to translate that to Eclipse projects.

Comment: Eclipse should be able to recognize git submodules.